# Linking to another website procedurally

Tags: nodes, 6, navigation

Hopefully this is a straightforward question.

I'm procedurally building nodes as I walk an XML feed, and am importing them into a production server.  I'm having issues importing node aliases, so I thought I could simply create links to the nodes as they will be on production (pathauto will take care of auto-aliasing them).

When I fill the href attribute of my link, instead of pointing to my website it points to my local server (it seems to be auto-changing my link).

I'm building my link like this:

```
$link = 'http://example.com/content/' . $current_node['name'];
$name = $current_node['name'];
```

and then assigning in my string

```
$output = "<a href='" . $link . "'>" . $name . "</a>":
```

However, as I mentioned, it ends up pointing local instead of direct to my outside node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating links, use [`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7).

```
$url = 'http://example.com/content/' . $current_node['name'];
$output = l($current_node['name'], $url, array('external' => TRUE));
```